# jQuery limit text function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with the columns CSS and what I want to do is create a jQuery function that calls a CSS class called "Content Columns" when the text of a paragraph reaches a certain amount of text. Otherwise it stays `width: 100%`.

This is the CSS i'm using

```css
-moz-column-count: 2;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-rule: none;
-webkit-column-count:2;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-rule: none;
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 10px;
column-rule: none;
margin-top:10px;
```

I know I need to make a if-statement that declares the length of a paragraph, I'm just not entirely sure how or where to start.

Comment: Look into `keyup` events - on `keyup` check the length of the text input, if it's passed the desired amount, add a class to what you need.

Comment: By paragraph do you mean a <p> element?  Do you want this if-statement to execute on page load, or is the content of the paragraph changing dynamically?

Comment: `$('p').filter(function(){ return $(this).height() > 400 }).addClass('contentColumns');` Here, 400 is an example of the maximum height a paragraph can have without being split into columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what action you want it check and also depends on what element you use it. On textbox u should use .val() on other elements u shoudl use html() or text() depending if you want inner html length or plain text. Also you can add another event listener, something like change, document keyup, etf.

But you can count letter by:

```js
var maxLength = 5;
$('.box').on('keyup',function(){
  if($('.box').val().length >= maxLength){
   alert("You have reached "+maxLength+" letter");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="box"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this - you need to make sure your text is in a parent element like:

```
<div class="text-group">
    <p>Haero nibh a turpis. Facilisi valetudo ut suscipit pecus olim nulla ad ut et. Autem vindico enim.</p>
    <p>Sino consequat dolore tincidunt tation vulputate valetudo antehabeo.</p>
</div>
```

Then in your script:

```
var threshold = '200' // cutoff number of characters to be 2-col
$('.text-group').each(function(i) {
     if ($(this).text().length > threshold) {
         $(this).addClass('content-columns');
     }
});
```

CSS: (unprefixed)

```
.content-columns {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
    column-rule: none;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your paragraphs have IDs, you can grab them with a selector and call .length on their .text().

```
$('#1').text().length
```

Or you can get all of them if you don't really care about specific ones and iterate.

```
paragraphs = $('p').get()
$.each(paragraphs, function (index) {
 console.log($(this).text().length);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd2a4ajc/)